# passing in structs to a void function with void type arguments

Tags: c

I'm new to both void * functions as well as structs.
I'm getting this error:

error: conflicting types for ‘aperiodic_task’

This is the function prototype:

```
void *aperiodic_task(void* arg)
```

I can basically pass in whatever I want, as long as I cast it, correct?

When I call the function, i'm doing the following:

```
aperiodic_task(&acontents);
```

"acontents" is a struct I setup to hold several different variables.

I thought for void style arguments I could basically pass in whatever I wanted. I'm probably missing something basic here, it's been a long day.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can pass any pointer into a `void *` argument. Your error **conflicting types for ‘aperiodic_task’** indicates that the compiler has seen two definitions of `aperiodic_task`, which has nothing to do with arguments you pass it when you try to call it. You either have a conflicting prototype, or you have not prototyped it at all.

Comment: yep... turns out i was trying to use the function before i had defined it. What a dumb mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user3287789 If this was the problem, please consider selecting it as the answer.